# Python Socket send and receive on same raspberry doesn't work

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi

I did a small program to receive data from an instrument. It works fine on windows, but I need to run it on Raspberry Pi and it doesn't work.
This is the code for the Server:

```
`from socket import socket, gethostbyname, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
import pymysql.cursors


PORT_NUMBER = 57806
SIZE = 1024

hostName = gethostbyname( '' )

mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
mySocket.bind( (hostName, PORT_NUMBER) )

print ("Test server listening on port {0}\n".format(PORT_NUMBER))

while True:

        (data,addr) = mySocket.recvfrom(SIZE)
        print("aa")
        data= data.decode("utf-8")
        data = data.split("      ", 2)[-1]
        data = data.partition(',')
        print (data[0])
        print(addr)
        connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                                         user='mezzo_mobile',
                                         password='',
                                         database='mezzo_mobile',
                                         charset='utf8mb4',
                                         cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        with connection:
                with connection.cursor() as cursor:

                            # Create a new record
                        sql = "INSERT INTO misure (mac,strumento, dato) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
                        if  str(addr[0])== "192.168.1.99":
                                cursor.execute(sql, ("00-05-2B-08-44-EB", "NOX", str(data[0])))
                                connection.commit()`
```

and here the code for the Client:

```
` import sys
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM

SERVER_IP   = '192.168.1.99'
PORT_NUMBER = 53700
SIZE = 1024

mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
mySocket.bind(('192.168.1.100', 57806))

while True:
        data = bytes.fromhex('014630303430335230303102313103')
        mySocket.sendto(data,(SERVER_IP,PORT_NUMBER))
        exit()  `
```

This instrument works like this: I send a packet containing this data "014630303430335230303102313103" and it send me back the measure. As I said it works fine on windows, but I need it on Raspberry.
On Raspberry if I run the server and then the client, the client throws the error:

```
OSerror: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

I don't know what to do and I don't know python well, any suggestion?

Comment: `SOCK_DGRAM` is UDP, which means you don't bind the client as there isn't a connection in UDP Based Protocols. Refer to this for more help: https://pythontic.com/modules/socket/udp-client-server-example. Remove the `mySocket.bind` from your client/caller.

Comment: @thethiny: Using bind of UDP should not be a problem, provided the address is correct...

Comment: @SergeBallesta I have tried to bind to UDP in python on a Raspberry pi before and I got into the same problem OP is having, that's why I'm suggesting it. Besides look, he's binding to the wrong Port.

Comment: I can see 2 different IP addresses on caller. What IP addresses are declared on your machine?

Comment: One more suggestion is to replace your IP with 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1 and see what works

Comment: Beware 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1 are not the same thing. First means any interface on the machine and can only be used to listen (TCP) or receive (UDP). Second is the loopback address and you can send (UDP) or connect (TCP) to it.

Comment: @SergeBallesta The address is correct the instrument needs a static ip to work so i know it and i know too the raspi ip.

Comment: This instrument requires that the call is made from 57806 or 57807, so this is why i binded the ip to the port, i tried to set the ip to 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.0 but it doesn-t work

Comment: 192.168.1.99 is the instrument ip and the other one is the raspberry.

Comment: Where do the scripts run? Both on the raspberry or on only caller runs on the rasp and listener on the *instrument*?

Comment: @SergeBallesta they both needs to run on the same raspberry, the instrument need that., i tried to use my pc as listener and raspberry as caller and viceversa but i don' get any result

Comment: If both run on same rasperry, why do they bind to different IP addresses?

Comment: So, i bind the socket because i need to bind the port, otherwise the instrument choose a random port from 50000 to 65525, and i don't want that

Comment: If they're both on the Raspberry then they're both on the same IP unless the Raspberry is connecting to an external service in which are u sure sockets are the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

I searched a bit on how socket on python works and find out that I can do all in the same script. This is how the code looks now:

```
import sys
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM

SERVER_IP   = '192.168.1.99'
PORT_NUMBER = 53700
SIZE = 1024

mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
mySocket.bind(('192.168.1.100', 57806))

while True:
        data = bytes.fromhex('014630303430335230303102313103')
        mySocket.sendto(data,(SERVER_IP,PORT_NUMBER))
        (data,addr) = mySocket.recvfrom(SIZE)
        print(data)
        exit()
```

and now it works as it is intended to be